# Concurrent drawRect:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch, nsview

I have a large array of objects (typically 500 - 2000) that render to the screen. Unfortunately, rendering is not exactly snappy at the moment.

Each object needs to perform some calculations which take up most of the time and finally draw itself to the screen, i.e. currently my `drawRect:` method looks essentially like this:
(*I've left out trivial optimizations like checking bounding rects vs. dirtyRect for the sake of readability*)

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
   for (Thing *thing in [self getThings])
   {
        [thing prepareForDrawing];
        [thing draw];
   }
}
```

An obvious candidate for concurrent processing, right?

I couldn't come up with a good approach to decouple preparation from the actual drawing operations, i.e. perform the pre-processing in parallel and somehow queue the drawing commands until all processing is done, then render all in one go.

However, thinking of the goodness that is [GCD](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) I came up with the following scheme.
It kind of sounds OK to me but being new to GCD and before running into weird multi-threading issues four weeks after a public release or just using a bad GCD design pattern in general I thought I'd ask for feedback.

**Can anybody see a problem with this approach - potential issues, or a better solution?**

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
   [[self getThings] enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent
                                      usingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
   {
      // prepare concurrently
      Thing *thing = (Thing*)obj;
      [thing prepareForDrawing];

      // always draw in main thread
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         [thing draw];
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: ... Did you try it? Did it work or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That won't work because the invocations of `[thing draw]` will happen outside of `-drawRect:` after it has completed. The graphics context will no longer be valid for drawing into that view.

Why are the "things" not prepared in advance? `-drawRect:` is for drawing, not computation. Any necessary expensive computation should have been done in advance.

Comment: Ah, crap. True. "*the main queue is associated with a CFRunLoop (for Core Foundation) or NSRunLoop (for Cocoa) on the main thread. These each "drain" the main queue at the end of their work cycles*".. and it did sound like such a nice idea.

Comment: It's all **computation directly related to the drawing**, i.e. converting internal representation into calls to the Cocoa drawing system. As I've mentioned in the question doing the computation in advance would basically mean to buffer all parameters to drawing commands (positions, colors, other context stuff) somewhere during that preprocessing, which would be quite an overhead, clumsy and error-prone.

Comment: Thanks for the accept. By the way, did you try just doing the `-prepareForDrawing` calls in a concurrent enumeration followed by synchronous drawing?

Comment: Unfortunately wouldn't work.. in the real project the tasks are slightly more decoupled and distributed amongst model classes and drawing strategy classes. The idea was to just 'join' all invocations to drawing calls (no matter where they happen) on the main thread - within scope of `drawRect:` being called. The latter apparently being the tricky bit..

Comment: Have you considered drawing to an offscreen buffer in background and then, on drawRect:, just copy the results?